# Push input value into an array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, for-loop, push

I am trying to push the value that was entered in a textbox into an array called new todos using a for loop.

I am looking for a solution that uses a for loop that pushes it into an array.

```
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  let newTodos = [];

  function addTodo( input ) {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      newTodos.push(input[i])
    }
  } 

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    const newList = list.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
    setList(newList);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => addTodo(input)}>Add</button>
      <ul> 
        {list.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            {todo.todo}
           <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>< AiFillDelete /></button>
         </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you just need to push input into newTodos like newTodos.push(input) without for loop. Your for loop push every characters of input into array instead of input

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're declaring your array within the component:

```
  let newTodos = [];

  function addTodo( input ) {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      newTodos.push(input[i])
    }
  }
```

Every time this component is called it'll be an empty array and the entries you've pushed will be no more.

You could move the declaration outside of the function and manage this data yourself:

```
let newTodos = [];

export default function App() {
  
  function addTodo( input ) {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      newTodos.push(input[i])
    }
  }

  // etc
```

I'd recommend `useState` (like you're doing with `list`):

```
  const [newTodos, setNewTodos ] = useState([]);
```

There is at least one cool thing about using state here: [State setters](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-parameters) can accept an updater function that is invoked with the pending state.  By using an updater function, your `addTodo` function to be simplified:

```
  function addTodo(input) {
    setNewTodos(state => state.concat(input));
  }
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-for-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-76460584-push-input-value-into-an-array-fpczcl) that shows `newTodos` updating when the `Add` button is clicked.